# ng-repeat list calls function recursively

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, recursion, angularjs-ng-repeat

Within a ng-repeat list i call a function {{ getDetailedData(id) }} to enrich the repeat items with more data. Within this function I call perform a-synchronous $http call in order to get more data. This results in recursive behaviour: the a-sync function gets called infinte.

when I remove the a-sync call the function gets called only as mauch as there are items in the list is the source for the repeat.

The a-sync call has a decent callback and surely doesn't call the originating function.

Need your thoughts on this.

**EDIT**

function in controller:

```
    $scope.getExtraData = function (id) {

                sFact.getSpotDetail(id, function (data) {
                    console.log('getSpotDetail', data);
                })
            return false;
}
```

ng-repeat in partial:

```
<div class="col-lg-4" style="display: block;" data-ng-repeat="cust in spots | filter: query">
            <h2 title="{{ cust.title }}">{{ $index + 1 }} {{ cust.title }}</h2>
            {{ getExtraData(cust.id) }}
</div>
```

a-sync function sFact(ory)

```
factory.getSpotDetail = function(id, callback) {

    var data = 'id=' + id;
    $http({
        url: "php/get_venue.php",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
        data: data,
        method: "POST"
    }).success(callback);
}
```

Comment: Do you append the new data to the item? I think angular refreshes the item in he ng-repeat, and therefore call again the function whenever the item is modified.

Comment: Can you show me your ng-repeat html and the javascript of the controller with the getDetailedData function.

Comment: Well actually I'm only logging the a-sync data which is returned, so I am doing with it. Stripped everything to the most basic setup:   itemFactory.getSpotDetail(id, function (data) { console.log('getSpotDetail::', data); })

Comment: Is `id` a property of the item in the ng-repeat? Like: `<ul ng-repeat="item in list"><li>{{getDetailedData(item.id)}}</li></ul>`

Comment: Ok just saw the updated post.

Comment: @jpmorin - as request the code.

Comment: I think that you should not do an ajax request inside of your ng-repeat because angular will refresh it whenever it feels like without your control. You should either get all your data before displaying it or have it loaded on a click event. I tried your code with a `$timeout` instead and it did what you experience.

Comment: Look a this JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/aQIYiMi/2/edit?html,js,output Open your dev console and look at what angular is doing. I cached the result of the async request.

Comment: I edited the demo (http://jsbin.com/aQIYiMi/3/edit) I added a query filter so you can see the ng-repeat gets refreshed whenever the query changes, so your async call would be retriggered everytime.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infinite loop with Angular expression binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466872/infinite-loop-with-angular-expression-binding)

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466872/infinite-loop-with-angular-expression-binding