# AngularJS $http.get() recursion killing browsers

Tags: angularjs

## The Problem

I've created a factory, which contains an `$http.get()` call. I believe this call somehow creates an infinite recursion--sometimes I see the `"10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"` error, other times it just makes the browser unresponsive so that I have to kill it.

If I remove the `$http.get()` call from the factory's `getOptionsForComponentType()`, and instead return a hardcoded array (and if I also remove the `.then()` call in the controller's `getAvailableOptions()`, the service actually returns data to the controller as expected. This leads me to believe that it is my `$http.get()` call that is creating the infinite recursion, not the service in and of itself.

What's wrong with my `$http.get()` call and/or service?

## The Code

### JS

All of my JS is in a single file, which is included on the page along with AngularJS. Here are (hopefully all of) the relevant parts:

```
var admin = angular.module('adminApp', []);
admin.factory('myService', function($http) {
    return {
        getOptionsForComponentType : function(componentType) {
            var url = '/griconfigurator/index/getComponentsOfTypeAction/component_type/' + componentType;
            return $http.get(url)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    };
});

admin.controller('configController', function(myService) {
    this.getAvailableOptions = function(componentType) {
        var options = [];
        myService.getOptionsForComponentType(componentType).then(
            function(data) {
                options = data;
                console.log('then success');
            },
            function(data) {
                console.log('then failure');
            }
        );
        return options;
    };
});
```

### Template

Then, in a template for a directive I created (let me know if I need to provide more details on my directives/templates):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Add/Remove</th>
        <th>SKU<br/><input ng-model='columnFilters.sku' type='text'></th>
        <th>category<br/><input ng-model='columnFilters.cat' type='text'></th>
        <th>sub cat<br/><input ng-model='columnFilters.subCat' type='text'></th>
        <th>Finish<br/><input ng-model='columnFilters.column_finish' type='text'></th>
        <th>Height<br/><input ng-model='columnFilters.column_height' type='text'></th>
        <th>Stock<br/><input ng-model='columnFilters.stock' type='text'></th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat='option in config.getAvailableOptions(component.type) | filter:columnFilters'>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Infinite loop with Angular expression binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466872/infinite-loop-with-angular-expression-binding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing would be to call the factory, apply it to a $scope variable, then write your ng-repeat like this:

option in SCOPEVAR | filter:blah

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call factory from `ng-repeat`. Each time the `config.getAvailableOptions(component.type)` changes, therefore it forces angular to do a new digest cycle when you update the values and  that leads to error like:

```
 "10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"
```

to force angular to do a digest cycle when you update the values.

To avoid this error, call factory from controller but not from `ng-repeat`