# how to turn a function into angular scope function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-scope

i've a code like below for calculate distance between two points, this is a code for my ionic project. i used **Angularjs-google-maps** by **allenhwkim**, and i want to turn the code into angular scope function so it can run on my **View**. by the way i get this code from my last question in this forum.

for calculate the distance :

```
var calcRoute = function(origin,destination,cb) {
        var dist;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var request = {
        origin:origin,
        destination:destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          cb(null, response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
        }
        else {
          cb('pass error information');
        }
      });
    };
```

code below for running the function and hold the result in $scope.A so i can call the result by typing {{A}} on my **View**

```
calcRoute("-7.048443, 110.441022","-7.048264, 110.440388", function (err, dist) {
    if (!err) {
      $scope.A = dist;
    }
});
```

the problem is, i just can use the function inside my **controller** and send the result with $scope, **but how to turn the code for example to {{ calc(ori,dest) }} and return the distance in my View**.

i've tried to do like this :

```
    $scope.calc = function(ori,dest){

    var calcRoute = function(origin,destination,cb) {
        var dist;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var request = {
        origin:origin,
        destination:destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          cb(null, response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
        }
        else {
          cb('pass error information');
        }
      });
    };


    calcRoute(ori,dest, function (err, dist) {
        if (!err) {
          return dist;
        }else{
                console.log("failed");
            }
    });
    return calcRoute();
};
```

and call the function inside my **View** like this :

```
{{calc("-7.048443, 110.441022","-7.048264, 110.440388")}}
```

it's not working,
return **undefined** and show console error below :

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
  {{calc("-7.048443, 110.441022","-7.048264, 110.440388")}}

InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object
```

hope anyone can help me,thanks :))

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can compute the function on the fly and print the return value.

What you can do is:

- Bind your function to a scope function `$scope.calc = function(x,y){...}`
- inside do the usual assignment `$scope.A = dist` .
- In the view just print `{{A}}`.
- To call the function simply use `calc(ori,dest)`. (from your code I didn't get where you should call it).

Comment: thanks for the answer @EsseTi ..
i call it from my controller ( javascript file ), so when i want to calculate more than one distance, i have to write the function multiple times with different $scope (exp: $scope.A,$scope.B..), because of that i want to the function become scope function and use **return dist** instead of **$scope.A = dist**..hope you get what i mean..:)

Comment: create a directive, each of them will have its own scope. so you can place it many times in the page

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned is that you are calling calcRoute twice, once with parameters, and once without:

```
calcRoute(ori,dest, function (err, dist) {
        if (!err) {
          return dist;
        }else{
                console.log("failed");
            }
    });
    return calcRoute();
```

The bigger problem is that you are not going to be able to evaulate your distance this way. Check out this SO post on evaluating asynchronous expressions.

[Infinite loop with Angular expression binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466872/infinite-loop-with-angular-expression-binding)

You're going to have to bind your values to $scope. If you're worried about cluttering up your controller with tons of $scope variables you could make an array and add multiple values to it, then use an ng-repeat to display the information in the view.