# Infinite loop when ng-repeat/ng-class calls a function which calls $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you have no idea what this is, please read this :[Infinite loop with Angular expression binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466872/infinite-loop-with-angular-expression-binding)

In the html file:

```
<ui ng-repeat="carrierDetail in carrierDetails">
    <li>
        <i ng-class="{'icon-sign-blank':getStatus(carrierDetail.carrierId)==0,'icon-green':getStatus(carrierDetail.carrierId)==1,'icon-orange':getStatus(carrierDetail.carrierId)==2,'icon-red':getStatus(carrierDetail.carrierId)==3}"></i>
        <ul ng-repeat="owner in getOwners(carrierDetail.carrierId)">
            <li>{{owner.ownerName}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ui>
```

As you see, a function `getStatus()` is called in `ng-class` and another function `getOwners()` is called in `ng-repeat`. And, both functions will call `$http` service:

```
$scope.getOwners = function(carrierId) {
    $http.get($scope.baseurl.smart,carrierId,1).then(function(data) {
        return data.data.carrierOwners; // Returns an aray
    }, function(data) {
        return [];
    });
}

$scope.getStatus = function(carrierId) {
    $http.get($scope.baseurl.smart,carrierId,1).then(function(data) {
        return [1, 2, 3].indexOf(data.data.carrierStatus) != -1 ? data.data.carrierStatus : 0; // Returns an integer
    }), function(data) {
        return 0;
    };
}
```

So, I already know that there are infinite calls for both functions. But I cannot come up with a solution. Maybe I can create a directive for either of the function. But I have no idea how to use the directive in `ng-class` or `ng-repeat`.  Are there any simpler ways? Thanks.

Comment: It seems your code is all wrong. You are putting function calls into ng-repeat, functions which run http requests, quite a bad way to go. I'll see if I can't help you out though.

Comment: I know I'm not giving an answer here, but first thing that comes to mind is making an http call for every iteration in ng-class seems excessive.  As for the function call in ng-repeat, if you must make a call (again for every iteration), like you said, create a directive and pass in the carrierDetail.carrierId.  Create a jsfiddle if you'd like us to review and revise.

Comment: @SoluableNonagon Yes. But I have to do that because I need to iterate into the array to get carrierId and pass this carrierId to the functiion to get an new array.

Comment: Then the carrierId should be read in the controller, not in the html

Comment: @SoluableNonagon Yes! You remind me of doing that. I can iterate into the array first in the controller and run functions for each id and store the results. Thanks so much!

Comment: consider returning a collection of statuses from the server

Comment: @heavyhorse Thanks. That's what i am gonna do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your html should not be calling functions pretty much **ever** (except for on click or something like that.

```
<ui ng-repeat="carrierDetail in carrierDetails">
    <li>
        <i ng-class="{'icon-sign-blank':carrierDetail.carrierId==0,'icon-green':carrierDetail.carrierId==1,'icon-orange':carrierDetail.carrierId==2,'icon-red':carrierDetail.carrierId==3}"></i>
        <ul ng-repeat="owner in owners">
            <li>{{owner.ownerName}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ui>
```

The JS, the general idea is:

```
// assuming controller defined:
$scope.carriers = some kind of array;

$scope.getOwners = function(carrierId) {
    $http.get($scope.baseurl.smart,carrierId,1).then(function(data) {
        return data.data.carrierOwners; // Returns an arary
    }, function(data) {
        return [];
    });
}

$scope.getStatus = function(carrierId) {
    $http.get($scope.baseurl.smart,carrierId,1).then(function(data) {
        return [1, 2, 3].indexOf(data.data.carrierStatus) != -1 ? data.data.carrierStatus : 0; // Returns an integer
    }), function(data) {
        return 0;
    };
}



for( var i in $scope.carriers){

    $scope.getOwners( $scope.carriers[ i ].carrierId ).then(function(success){
        // add data to array
    });

}
```