# using ng-repeat to populate table rows with data from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a JS function called `current_item.get_user_history()` that returns an array , by making and API call, that looks something along the lines of this:

```
things[0]:
 thing_id: 5
 user_id: 23
 paddle_no: 1234
 item_id: 893
 price: 5000

things[1]:
 thing_id: 4
 user_id: 67
 paddle_no: 6743
 item_id: 893
 price: 4500

... and so on
```

I want to be able to take data from this array to populate a table using an ng-repeat.

```
<div class="bid_history">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>
            Column 1
          </th>
          <th>
            Column 2
          </th>
          <th>
            Column 3
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="thing in current_item.get_user_history() track by thing.id">
        {{thing.user_id}} {{thing.price}}
        </tr>

      </table>
  </div>
```

For some reason nothing gets rendered, and it seems to do a lot of repeating because I get an unstoppable number of errors in the chrome console. Any help is appreciated to explain exactly how one uses `ng-repeat`.

Comment: It's typically recommended not to iterate over the results of a function, but to instead use the function to assign to a scope variable, then iterate over that.

Comment: okay i will try that out

Comment: Can you post the errors if its not solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that digest cycle was returning a promise and I had to turn it into an object instead.

I was originally doing this:

```
my_api.get_user_history(self.id);
```

and had to add this to that line:

```
.then(function(data){self.user_history = data});
```

Part of the problem was also what @Ealon mentioned as well. I also decided to store it in a local variable instead of having the result of a function returned. I posted this answer because each of the above answer were all valid pieces that I needed to consider and put together to fix my problem. Thank you all for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a function that triggers `$digest()` (like `$http`, `$timeout`) in `ng-repeat`. It causes infinite `$digest()` loop.

There are explanations:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/705 or [angular Infinite $digest Loop in ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847336/angular-infinite-digest-loop-in-ng-repeat).

And I made the same mistake before :)

[Infinite loop when ng-repeat/ng-class calls a function which calls $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440885/infinite-loop-when-ng-repeat-ng-class-calls-a-function-which-calls-http)

You have to save `current_item.get_user_history()` data first and then use `ng-repeat` to call the data.

```
scope.things= urrent_item.get_user_history();

<tr ng-repeat="thing in things track by thing.id">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**
Don't call a function on `ngRepeat` for return items.  Store the item array on a property in the scope.

`$scope.user_history = current_item.get_user_history();`

If in fact you really need to do this you can fix it with one of the following:

1. Do not create new object on every `current_item.get_user_history()` call.
2. If you need to create new objects you can add `hashKey` method for them.  See [this topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/IEIQok-YkpU) for examples.

**Medium Answer**
You generally do not want to iterate over a function in ng-repeat.  The reason is that `current_item.get_user_history()` returns an array with new object.  This object does not have a `hashKey` and does not exist in `ngRepeat` cache.  So `ngRepeat` on each `watch.get` generates new scope for it with new watch for `{{thing.id}}`.  This watch on first `watch.get()` has `watch.last == initWatchVal`.  So then `watch.get() != watch.last`. So then `$digest` starts a new traverse.  Then `ngRepeat` creates a new scope with a new watch and so on.  Then after 10 traverses you will get an error.

**Long Answer**
Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336897/how-to-loop-through-items-returned-by-a-function-with-ng-repeat) for a very well done explanation of how this works.