# Restangular nested child query infinite loop

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I need to run a query to retrieve a list of children from each parent.

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    <td>{{parent.id}}</td>
    <td>{{parent.name}}</td>
    <td>
        <li ng-repeat="child in getChildren(parent.id)">
            {{child}}
        </li>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, Restangular) {
...
$scope.getChildren = function(parentId) {
    console.log(parentId); //called over and over

    //should GET e.g. /api/parents/1/children
    return Restangular.one('parents', parentId).getList('children').then(function(children) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(children)); //never hit
        return children;
    })
}
```

I can see the correct API endpoint is getting called, but the getChildren() function is called repeatedly for the same parentId. It also never seems to return. I'm sure its something obvious - what am I doing wrong?

Seems related to this: [Infinite loop with Angular expression binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466872/infinite-loop-with-angular-expression-binding) however that example doesnt use Restangular.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why it would be infinitely running. It could have something to do with AngularJs' digest cycle.

To avoid this problem entirely, one solution could be:

You have a `$scope.parents` variable. From that variable (or at least once it's initialized) you could do:

```
$scope.children = {};

for (var parent in $scope.parents) {
    // store parent id for easy access
    var parentId = $scope.parents[parent].id;
    // get the children
    Restangular.one('parents', parentId).getList('children')
        .then(function(children) {
        // access the parentResource object of the returned object to
        // get the parent id
        $scope.children[children.parentResource.id] = children;
    })
}
```

This way, the children are accessible through a object (keyed by parent id). Then in your html, you'd have:

```
<li ng-repeat="child in children[parent.id]"></li>
```

and rather than making a function call, you'd just be accessing a $scope variable.