# passing function as two way binding re-triggers $digest - infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass in a value from a parent directive (bound to controller X) to a child directive, update it, then pass it back all the way to the controller X `updateItem` function.

This causes the parent controller X to receive the updated value, which triggers a new `$digest` loop, and passes the item down through the chain, and so on. This causes an infinite loop ([discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466872/infinite-loop-with-angular-expression-binding)).

I need to update the value from the child directive though, so how can I avoid re-triggering the `$digest` cycle once the controller's `$scope.items` is updated?

Parent controller X:

```
$scope.updateItem = function(item) {
  $scope.items = item;
};
```

Parent directive template: Bound to parent controller

```
<div>
   <custom-phrases item-to-update="item" update-item="updateItem"></custom-phrases>
</div>
```

Parent directive js:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('itemlist',
    function($rootScope, $state) {
      return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'directives/cms/itemlist/itemlist.tpl.html',
        scope: {
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            //
        },
        controller: parentControllerX
      };
    });
```

Child directive js:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .directive('customPhrases',
    function($rootScope) {
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
          itemToUpdate: '=',
          updateItem: '=',
        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/cms/customPhrases/custom_phrases_directive.tpl.html',
        link: function(scope, element) {

          scope.itemToUpdate.attr1 += 1;
          scope.itemToUpdate.attr2 += 1;

          // then pass it back to parent directive
          scope.updateItem(scope.itemToUpdate);
          ...
```

---

If I change to `{{ item }}`:

```
<div>
   <custom-phrases item-to-update="{{ item }}" update-item="updateItem"></custom-phrases>
</div>
```

And pass it into the child directive, it comes through as a string and not an object.

---

EDIT 2:

If I simply update `items` in the child directive, like so:

```
   scope.items = {
     test: 'testing 123'
   };
```

And maintain 2-way binding in the child directive:

```
items: '=',
```

`scope.items` is never updated at the parent directive and controller level.

Comment: What is supposed to kick off the update?

Comment: The item is passed down through the chain to the child directive on instantiation of the controller and directives. The child directive updates the value and returns to the parent directive and controller

Comment: So it only updates once then?

Comment: The issue is... it should only update once... but when I update it in the child directive and pass it back to parent controller X's `$scope.updateItem` and update `$scope.items` with the new item... it triggers the templates to update and a new $digest loop, thereby repeating the process

Comment: See my answer. I think you're just making this way too hard.

Comment: Try set scope: false and transclude: false in the child directive so that you will have the same scope(with parent element). Also remove all the isolating scope in the child directive

Comment: I don't get it. You pass `item` to the child directive but want to update `items` in the parent directive? That doesn't make sense to me. I also don't understand why you use `=` instead of `&` to bind the function.

Comment: @zeroflagL yes because I have a save function in the parent scope that I need to pass the updated value to

Comment: `item` already IS updated. What's `items` for?

Comment: Its not appearing as updated in the parent scope

Answer (score 0):

If your child directive taking care to update the value and passed it back parent then you don't need two way binding with `=`.

You can use one way binding with `<`

```
scope: {
      itemToUpdate: '<', // use one way binding
      updateItem: '=',
    }
```

EDIT :

My bad : 
You already having two way data binding,you dont need to pass it back from child directive.

`scope.updateItem(scope.itemToUpdate);`. //not needed

It will automatically available there.

Comment: Please see update above. How can I now parse the object in the child controller? It's coming thru as a string

Comment: I can use JSON parse I suppose

Comment: @Growler then `scope.itemToUpdate` will be string and not variable.You can achieve the same things with `@`.i dont know what operation u doing with this passed data.So,not cleared why you passsing it as interpolated value

Comment: See above. I'm simply changing some of the properties on the object in the child directive then passing it back

Comment: This is still causing the infinite loop

Comment: @Growler please check EDIT

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you're calling the update in your link function. So, you're updating the item, which causes the view to update, which causes a digest cycle and then you're looping forever.

Your approach doesn't make any sense. If your parent controller has the function that's going to update your item, why are you bothering to bind the function at all? Just bind `item` and let the parent controller handle the updating without trying to "pass it" back and forth. Whatever is bound to the attributes is coming from the parent, so just add it to `item` directly in the update function as parameters.

You're overcomplicating what is a simple binding solution by trying to call the parent controller's update method from the child instead of just letting the two-way binding do it's magic on `item`.

Comment: Please see my above comment. I started off with simple by updating the `$scope.items` in my child directive, but it's never updated.